# Times New Roman with fontspec missing after update

Tags: errors, fontspec, times

After this morning's update of all my packages, Times New Roman cannot be found.

Here's the file:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

\begin{document}

Text

\end{document}
```

Here's the [log file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ilg82iec7lrh5jk/Log_file.log?dl=0).

The main error parts:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\__fontspec_init_ttc:n #1->\str_if_eq:eeT                                            
{\str_lower_case:f {\l__fontspec_e...
l.4 \setmainfont{Times New Roman}
```

(...)

```
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
! fontspec error: "font-not-found"
! 
! The font "Times New Roman" cannot be found.
```

Before the update everything was working fine. I tried reinstalling fontspec.

I'm not very good at reading log files, so any ideas would be appreciated.

EDIT: I'm on Windows 10.

Comment: It would probably also be a good idea to mention which system you are on. From the log (note we generally do not like likes to external files, they may disappear in the future making the question unusable to others) that you are using miktex. I can also see that your miktex is not properly up to date. Note the expl3 date is from 2017, thus your user part of your miktex installation is very much not up to date and since it takes precedence you get into trouble. On my up to date texlive system (which does not split things into miktex and user installations) expl3 is from 2019

Comment: In miktex always update both in user and in admin mode!!

Comment: @simon it was miktex we were asking for. See Ulrikes comment. This is (sadly) a very common error among miktex users)

Comment: @Ulrike, daleif Yes, I seem to have made this mistake. I updated in both modes and the error is gone. Thank you!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because problem disappear after updating of the MikTeX installation.